Why does manim create a circle for a set of points that form an ellipse?
trying to animate the orbit of a planet in manim . If I plot the data returned from the compute_orbit() function in matplotlib for say , I get an ellipse , but the same set of points create a circle in manim. I'm not sure why manim behaves this way !
Code Snippet
from manim import *
from astroquery.jplhorizons import Horizons
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
def get_initial_conditions(planet_id):
        obj = Horizons(id=planet_id, location='@sun', epochs=2000.0)
        eph = obj.vectors()
        position = np.array([eph['x'][0], eph['y'][0], eph['z'][0]]) * 1.496e11
        velocity = np.array([eph['vx'][0], eph['vy'][0], eph['vz'][0]])  * (1.496e11/86400)    
        scale_factor_position = 1  
        scale_factor_velocity = 1  
        return {
            "position": np.array(position) / scale_factor_position,
            "velocity": np.array(velocity) / scale_factor_velocity
        }

def compute_orbit(central_mass=1.989e30,rotating_mass=5.972e24, dt=10000, total_time=31536000):
        initial_conditions_data = get_initial_conditions(399)
        initial_conditions = [
            initial_conditions_data['position'][0], initial_conditions_data['velocity'][0],
            initial_conditions_data['position'][1], initial_conditions_data['velocity'][1],
            initial_conditions_data['position'][2], initial_conditions_data['velocity'][2]
                            ]

        def f(t, state):
            x, vx, y, vy, z, vz = state
            r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2) + 1e-5  
            G = 6.67430e-11
            Fx = -G * central_mass * rotating_mass * x / r**3
            Fy = -G * central_mass * rotating_mass * y / r**3
            Fz = -G * central_mass * rotating_mass * z / r**3
            return [vx, Fx / rotating_mass, vy, Fy / rotating_mass, vz, Fz / rotating_mass]


        t_span = (0, total_time)
        t_eval = np.arange(0, total_time, dt)  
        sol = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(
        f, 
        t_span, 
        initial_conditions, 
        t_eval=t_eval, 
        rtol=1e-3, 
        atol=1e-6)
        x = sol.y[0] / 1e11 
        y = sol.y[2]  / 1e11
        z = sol.y[4]  / 1e11
        positions = np.column_stack((x, y, z))
        return positions


class Space(ThreeDScene):
    def construct(self):
        orbit = ThreeDVMobject()
        data = compute_orbit()
        orbit.set_points_as_corners(data)
        self.add(orbit)
        self.wait(3)



By default, matplotlib doesn't use equal scales for the x- and y-axes

@BenGrossmann right , I just scaled the orbit while applying different scale values for each axis , indeed I get an ellipse!

I don't understand your comment. Are you saying that you changed something so that you now get an ellipse in manim, that you had already accounted for axis-scaling in matplotlib, or some other thing?

yes , you mentioned that matplotlib doesn't use equal scales for the axes , but manim does use equal scales for the axes , so i changed the scaling for axes in manim as well.

Got it, thank you for clarifying
